# Geofire callback error

Tags: android, firebase, callback, overriding, geofire

I am trying to use the `getLocation()` method from GeoFire, and it requires two callbacks. However, I am having `Method does not override method from its superclass` error with the @Override `onLocationResult()` and `onCancelled()`. How to fix this?

Note: My class extends Fragment, and the `getLocation()` is within `onCreateView()`.

Code:

```
public class Browse extends Fragment {
    ...
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase; // NEW
    private GeoFire geoFire;
    private String businessID;
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse, container, false);

        SharedPreferences businessID1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("BUSINESS_ID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        businessID = businessID1.getString("businessID", "businessIDNotFound");

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("geo_fire"); // NEW

        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(mDatabase); // NEW

        geoFire.getLocation(businessID, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override <<<--ERROR HERE !
            public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("The location for key %s is [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                } else {
                    System.out.println(String.format("There is no location for key %s in GeoFire", key));
                }
            }

            @Override <<<--ERROR HERE !
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.err.println("There was an error getting the GeoFire location: " + databaseError);
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** My gradle build error:

Error:(90, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Error:(99, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Error:(89, 41) error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to com.firebase.geofire.LocationCallback

Dependency: compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you didn't initialize `GeoFire`. In order to have access to GeoFire's methods, you need to create a new object of the class like this:

```
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(yourDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid()));
```

Then you can use the setter and getters. Please see this [example](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java).

**Edit:** Seeing your updated code, the problem is that you are overriding the `onCancelled()` method in an incorrect way. You need to change this line of code:

```
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
```

with

```
public void onCancelled(com.firebase.client.FirebaseError firebaseError) {
```

The argument is of type `FirebaseError` and not `DatabaseError`.

Also try to do the following steps with Android Studio. In the activy in which you get the error, remove both methods, `onLocationResult()` and `onCancelled`. Then press `CTRL+O` -> choose both methods -> click Ok. This will helps you override both methods in a correct way.

**Later Edit:** After many tries, the solution that solved the problem was to update all Firebase dependencies to the last version, which is for the moment `11.2.0`. Because `GeoFire 2.x` is based on the `new 3.x release` of Firebase, it will work with latest Firebase Android SDK version. In this case `11.2.0`.

Comment: I have added 3 lines of code (see //NEW) in edit. The error still occurs.

Comment: It still does not solve it. How does these solve the 'Method does not override method from its superclass error'?

Comment: there is no onCancelled() option. Could you please show a sample code of how it should look like? It would really help.

Comment: [Interface LocationCallback](https://geofire-java.firebaseapp.com/docs/com/firebase/geofire/LocationCallback.html) has two methods `onCancelled(com.firebase.client.FirebaseError firebaseError)` and `onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location)` which you need to override. Are you sure that error is coming here and not in another part of your code?

Comment: To override those methos, click CTRL+O after the last curly brace -> new LocationCallback() {

Comment: I have done that, for some reason onCancelled() is not an option. I have updated my question to include the gradle build errors.

Comment: Please share also the build.gradle file. Not only the error.

Comment: what do you mean by build.gradle file (sorry newbie here)

Comment: the file where you import the `dependencies`. Where you Firebase. `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'` and so on.

Comment: Do you have this line of code `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'`in your dependencies?

Comment: I have the 11:0:4 version.

Comment: You need to update all the to the last version. `geofire-android:2.1.1` works only with version 11.2.0.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for being so patient! If you update your answer I will accept it! Thanks a bunch!